# Comparing string matches between groups by category

Tags: r

I have a large dataset in the following form with text strings extracted from a corpus:

```
Category      Group         Text_Strings 
1             A             c(string1, string2, string3)
1             A             c(string1, string3)
1             B             character(0)
1             B             c(string1)
1             B             c(string3)

2             A             character(0)
2             A             character(0)
2             B             c(string1, string3)

3             A             c(string1, string2, string3)
3             A             character(0)
3             A             c(string1)
3             B             character(0)
3             B             c(string1, string2, string3)
```

...where A and B have string1 and string3 in common in Category 1; none in common in Category 2; and all three in common in Category 3.

I'd like to obtain a count of the number of strings that match between Groups A and B for each Class. String matches can be in any order; e.g. c(string1, string2) evaluated against c(string2, string1) should be counted as two matches. Also, matches should only be between unique strings in each category; e.g. c(string1, string2), c(string1) vs. c(string2, string1) should still only be two matches. For example:

```
Category      Group         Text_Strings 
4             A             c(string1, string2, string3)
4             A             c(string1)
4             B             c(string1)
4             B             c(string1)
```

... would yield only one match even though string1 is repeated.

My final output should look like this:

```
Category     Matches
1            2
2            0 
3            3
4            1
```

I did quite a bit of research but I wasn't able to figure out an answer on my own. It occurs to me that I might be able to subset the dataframe by Group, somehow aggregate/concatenate strings over Categories, then use lapply() and intersect()... something like

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)[1]) {
    data$matches[i] <- sum(intersect(subset(data, Group=="A")$Text_Strings[i], 
                                     subset(data, Group=="B")$Text_Strings[i])) 
}
```

Of course this is missing steps and doesn't work, but am I on the right track? Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**: jeremycg's solution was extremely helpful, but my data was so messy that it wouldn't accept parse(). Thanks to another user in a different thread, I got around this problem by splitting rows based on comma separators rather than trying to unnest directly:

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
     separate_rows(Text_Strings, sep = ",") %>% # split on commas
      dmap_at("Text_Strings", ~ gsub("^c\\(\"|\")$|\"", "", .x))
```

This produced the same unnested data but was *much* cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% unnest() %>% #spread out the nested columns
      distinct() %>% #remove dupes
      group_by(Category) %>% #by Category
      summarise(out = sum(Text_Strings[Group  == 'A'] %in% Text_Strings[Group  == 'B'])) #sum the overlap
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  Category   out
     (int) (int)
1        1     2
2        2     0
3        3     3
```

You actual data is pretty messed up - you should try and fix whatever is outputting it to a 'long format'. Here's a clunky fix:

```
x$listcites =  gsub('\\\\n', '',x$listcites) #remove newlines
x$listcites = gsub("\"", "'", x$listcites, fixed = TRUE) #remove quotes to singles
x$listcites[grepl('^[^c]',x$listcites)] = paste("c('", x$listcites[grepl('^[^c]',x$listcites)],"')", sep = '') #fix single lines to same format
x$listcites = sapply(x$listcites, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))) #eval to vecs in dataframe
x %>% unnest() %>%
      distinct %>%
      group_by(case_num) %>%
      summarise(out = sum(listcites[type  == 'claimant'] %in% listcites[type  == 'court'])) #sum the overlap
```

Comment: Can you explain why the code doesn't run without redefining the strings as a,b,c? It gets stuck at the sapply() part and spits out an error: "object 'string1' not found." This is relevant because there are too many strings to define this way in my dataset.

Comment: This is an artifact of the way you posted your data - I don't have access to what you have defined as string1/2/3, and it is either enclosing them in quotes or defining them as something for parsing. You presumably have them defined as strings in your actual dataframe, so can skip the data input step.

Comment: I included some representative ASCII data in the question. sapply() produces: " Error in parse(text = toString(x)) : <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol 1: israel v." I realized it's because the quotes around strings with only one element aren't escaped. Now I just have to figure out how to fix that...

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond to answer my question. Works beautifully on the example data. Unfortunately it isn't taking to my actual data... one "unexpected symbol" error after another when calling parse(). The joys of working with OCR'd data. Each time I fix one another crops up, and they're very hard to debug since the error doesn't report the row number. Can you suggest another way to read in the nested strings without parse(), which seems overly picky? Maybe expand.grid() would do it?