# Comparison of elements in column between groups

Tags: r

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580501/comparing-string-matches-between-groups-by-category) contains a helpful explanation for how to obtain a count of the number of matching strings between groups. However, I'd like to figure out how many strings are unique to a *particular group* for each category.

Example:

```
Category      Group         Text_Strings 
1             A             string1
1             A             string2
1             B             string1
1             B             string2
1             B             string3

2             A             string1
2             A             string3
2             B             string3

3             A             string1
3             A             string2
3             A             string3
3             B             string4
3             B             string5
```

For Group B, the function would return one unique string in Category 1, none in 2, and two in 3.

```
Category     Count
1            1
2            0
3            2
```

For Group A, it would return:

```
Category     Count
1            0
2            1
3            3
```

Following the advice on the other thread, finding unique strings should be as simple as something like:

```
df %>% 
  distinct %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(uniques = sum(
    strings[group == 'A'] %!in% strings[group == 'B']))
```

...but I don't know how to take the difference for only one category at a time. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: For Group A it should be Count = [0, 1, 3]

Comment: Thanks for catching typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using `by`, `sapply`, and `aggregate`. Using `by`, we calculate how many other string matches there are for each string by category. Our calculation is performed by iterating through each string in `Text_Strings` using `sapply`. After this is performed, we `unlist` the results, and `cbind` the result to our original data, `dat`. Then, we perform a simple call to `aggregate` to see how many `OtherMatches == 0` there are for each category and group.

```
dat <- cbind(dat, 
             'OtherMatches' = unlist(
               by(dat, dat$Category, function(x)
                 sapply(x$Text_Strings, 
                        FUN = function(y) sum(y == x$Text_Strings) - 1))))

dat2 <- aggregate(OtherMatches ~ Category + Group, data = dat, 
          FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0))

setNames(dat2, c('Category', 'Group', 'Count'))

  Category Group Count
1        1     A     0
2        2     A     1
3        3     A     3
4        1     B     1
5        2     B     0
6        3     B     2
```

#### Another way

Here's another way, usingthe split-apply-combine framework again. This time, we'll use a little base `R` and a little `dplyr`. First, we `split` the data by `Category`. Then, we use `lapply` to act on the split data, using `cbind` to add a new column calculated (as before) using `sapply`. We combine the data using `unsplit`, and then we `group_by` `Category` and `Group`, and then `summarise` as we did before.

```
library(dplyr)

split(dat, dat$Category) %>%   
  lapply(., FUN = function(x) 
    cbind(x, 
          'OtherMatches' = 
            sapply(x$Text_Strings, 
                   FUN = function(y) sum(y == x$Text_Strings) - 1))) %>%
  unsplit(dat$Category) %>%
  group_by(Category, Group) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(OtherMatches == 0))

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: Category [?]

  Category Group Count
     <int> <chr> <int>
1        1     A     0
2        1     B     1
3        2     A     1
4        2     B     0
5        3     A     3
6        3     B     2
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(
  Category = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
  Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
  Text_Strings = c("string1", "string2", "string1", "string2", "string3",
                   "string1", "string3", "string3", "string1", "string2", 
                   "string3", "string4", "string5")), 
  .Names = c("Category", "Group", "Text_Strings"), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and very detailed explanation! Strangely each method gives me a different count wrt my actual dataset, but just something for me to figure out on my end. Thanks again!!